# What does the code "val jsonObj = json as JsonObject" mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following sample code is from a webpage, could you tell me what the code `val jsonObj = json as JsonObject` mean? Is the word `as` keyword of Kotlin?

Thanks!

```
open class WeatherDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<WeatherObject> {

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): WeatherObject? {
        val jsonObj = json as JsonObject

        val wheather = WeatherObject()
        val wind = WindObject()

        val jsonWeatherArray = jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("weather").get(0)
        val jsonMainObj = jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("main")
        val jsonWindObj = jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("wind")

        wheather.main = jsonWeatherArray.asJsonObject.get("main").asString
        wheather.description = jsonWeatherArray.asJsonObject.get("description").asString
        wheather.temp = jsonMainObj.get("temp").asFloat
        wheather.tempMax = jsonMainObj.get("temp_max").asFloat
        wheather.tempMin = jsonMainObj.get("temp_min").asFloat
        wheather.humidity = jsonMainObj.get("humidity").asInt
        wind.speed = jsonWindObj.get("speed").asFloat
        wind.deg = jsonWindObj.get("deg").asFloat
        wheather.wind = wind

        return wheather

    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=kotlin+as+keyword

Comment: Can someone explain why there are so many duplicate answers here? The two answers to this question are identical, except for the fact that the _second_ one is a less detailed version of the first one, which was posted one minute earlier. Why do people tend to answer the same thing when there is already a correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json` is being casted to `JsonObject` . `as` is a cast keyword in Kotlin.

`as` provides us with unsafe cast. That is an exception will be thrown if the cast isn't possible.

[Further reading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator)

Answer (score 1):

`as` is a type cast operator.

So this just cast your `json` object of `JsonElement` to `JsonObject`.

Just like Java equivalent of `JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) json;`

For more read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator

Comment: Just for the sake of completion: The Java equivalent would be `JsonObject jsonObj = (JsonObject) json;`